# conversion from milliseconds to hours in C

Tags: c

i have a variable A expressed in Hours and a variable B expressed in milliseconds. I need to easily convert milliseconds to hours to do this.

```
if (!bip)
{
   fControllerSystemOutputSet(gControllerData[1].ControllerId, sys_cfg.IM.OutputEnable, 1);
   fControllerSystemOutputSet(gControllerData[1].ControllerId, sys_cfg.IM.Print, 1);        
   bip = true;
   Maint.PSUTime += sys_cfg.IM.APTime  / 60 / 60 / 1000 ; 
}
```

it's not difficult but i can't find an easy formula to apply

Comment: Why is your solution not good enough?

Comment: That looks like a formula. Have you written code?

Comment: i couldn't find this formula anywhere so i thought that was better to ask if it was the correct way

Comment: How is the code you posted related to your program or to your variables? Where is variable `A`? Where is variable `B`? `was the correct way` How would you convert hours to millisecond and back, on paper?

Comment: yes is an extracted from code... to convert hours to milliseconds the formula is  int milliseconds = hours * 60 * 60 *1000; i've thought that to do the opposite it is only a divison instead of a moltiplication

Comment: So did it work as you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assuming there are two variables `A` & `B`.

```
long long B; // B is the required milliseconds

printf("Enter the required ms: ");
scanf("%lli", &B);

double A = (double) B / 3600000; // to hours

printf("%lf\n", A);
```

**Disclaimer:** Your program has no such declaration which is written in your question. But for sake of simplicity, I just showed the easy method conversion of milliseconds into hours.

Comment: perfect, that was what i was searching for